# Node postgres constraints

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, node-postgres

I'm trying to write a constraint code that will display a message when someone tries to search for an id that doesn't exist in the database (PostgreSQL) but the if statement code below doesn't seem to do anything I keep getting status 200 ok on postman even though the id doesn't seem to exist. How can I fix this?

Code below:

Database query:

```js
const findFruit = async (req, res) => {

    const {id } = req.params;
    try {
        const findfru = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE fruit_id=$1", [id]);

        if (!findfru ) {
            return res.status(400).send(e)
        }

        res.json(findfru .rows[0])

    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send(e)

    }
}
```

Route API:

```js
router.get("Fruits/:id", findFruit )
```

Comment: What is `e` in `res.status(400).send(e)`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with database constraints.

Answer (score 3):

If the ID isn't in the database the query still succeeds, it just returns no rows. You should check the number of rows explcitily:

```
if (findfru.rows.length === 0) {
    return res.status(400).send(`${id} not found`);
}
```

Comment: I see, it works perfectly fine now thanks!